# Install Python3.6 Version of Boost-Python3

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, boost, boost-python

I have been using Boost Python to write a C++ module to be exposed to Python. I have Boost and Boost-Python3 (version 1.68.0) using Homebrew on MacOS High Sierra. This has been compiled for Python 3.7, which is listed as a dependency for Boost-Python3.

However, I would like to use Boost with Python 3.6. Is there any way in which I can downgrade my version of Boost-Python3 so that it is compatible with Python3.6 instead of 3.7?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution from this page: https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-python/issues/154.

To bring boost-python3 back down to a Python3.6 compatible version, you need to downgrade from version 1.68.0 to 1.67.0. This can be done via:

```
brew uninstall boost-python3
```

then

```
brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/6a77cdaac520f5d2f0a38f30606e91b7023ee5f0/Formula/boost-python3.rb
```